# DynamoDB call history?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, throughput

I have a DynamoDB application and it seems to be running well and using normal throughput generally.  However once in a while it seems to spike pretty high (latest kicked up over 300, normal is around 10-20 max).  I've looked through the code and I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what it is that is causing these spikes.  Is there any type of history of the calls in DynamoDB that could tell me what exactly were the calls that caused the spiking?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the **cloudtrail** logs for the dynamoDB.It will deliver these log files to **S3** bucket. Taken directly from the AWS Docs :-

> DynamoDB is integrated with CloudTrail, a service that captures
>   low-level API requests made by or on behalf of DynamoDB in your AWS
>   account and delivers the log files to an Amazon S3 bucket that you
>   specify. CloudTrail captures calls made from the DynamoDB console or
>   from the DynamoDB low-level API. Using the information collected by
>   CloudTrail, you can determine what request was made to DynamoDB, the
>   source IP address from which the request was made, who made the
>   request, when it was made, and so on. To learn more about CloudTrail,
>   including how to configure and enable it, see the AWS CloudTrail User
>   Guide.

Please follow the [aws dynamoDB cloudtrail logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) to enable it.

Comment: Ok that looks like what I was looking for, thank you!  I don't have an S3 set up but I'm sure I can get it going with that direction, thank you very much.

Comment: @sfaust , pleasure is mine :)

Comment: the official document is, as usual, hard to follow.